# How to line break between to variables in an alert box?

Tags: javascript

Currently I have 
window.alert('Wrong Answer ' +why+ '' +cite);
I probably should use a modal instead,but it's easier to use an alertbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use `\n`. That is the "line break" character: `alert(\`Wrong answer:\n${why}\`)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var why, cite;
window.alert("Wrong Answer \n" + why + "\n" + cite);
```